Next.js and Sanity switch locale to default URL
I developed a website on Next js using Sanity CMS. AppRouter technology. My website supports English add German languages. The thing is that there is no home page on the main domain, because the folder structure is as follows: app/[lang]/page.tsx.
Accordingly, the home page is always located at mysite.com/en or mysite.com/de. Is it possible to somehow reconfigure the project so that the home page is located at mysite.com without a slash? Do you know how I can switch address '/en' to '/'?
I have set up internalization this way:
// i18n.config.ts

const languages = [
  { id: 'de', title: 'German' },
  { id: 'en', title: 'English', isDefault: true },
];

const i18n = {
  languages,
  base: languages.find((item) => item.isDefault)?.id,
};

export { i18n };

// middleware.ts

import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import type { NextRequest } from "next/server";

import { i18n } from "@/i18n.config";

import { match as matchLocale } from "@formatjs/intl-localematcher";
import Negotiator from "negotiator";

function getLocale(request: NextRequest): string | undefined {
  const negotiatorHeaders: Record<string, string> = {};
  request.headers.forEach((value, key) => (negotiatorHeaders[key] = value));

  const locales: string[] = i18n.languages.map(lang => lang.id);
  const languages = new Negotiator({ headers: negotiatorHeaders }).languages();

  const locale = matchLocale(languages, locales, i18n.base || "id");
  return locale;
}

export function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  const pathname = request.nextUrl.pathname;
  const pathnameIsMissingLocale = i18n.languages.every(
    locale =>
      !pathname.startsWith(`/${locale.id}/`) && pathname !== `/${locale.id}`
  );

  if (pathnameIsMissingLocale) {
    const locale = getLocale(request);
    return NextResponse.redirect(
      new URL(
        `/${locale}${pathname.startsWith("/") ? "" : "/"}${pathname}`,
        request.url
      )
    );
  }
}

export const config = {
  // Matcher ignoring `/_next/` and `/api/`
  matcher: [
    "/((?!api|_next/static|admin|structure|robots|sitemap|_next/image|favicon.ico).*)"
  ]
};


There's no problem if your website's homepage redirects to a path with locale, because this supports internationalization, but i'll try to provide a solution from what i understand.
You can change your if statement so that when the pathname is homepage you do not add locale to it, but this comes with an inconvenient, you'll have to create a separate page at app/page.tsx (Notice that there's no [lang]), you can use the default language for that page which is english.
  if (pathnameIsMissingLocale && pathname !== "/") {
    const locale = getLocale(request);
    return NextResponse.redirect(
      new URL(
        `/${locale}${pathname.startsWith("/") ? "" : "/"}${pathname}`,
        request.url
      )
    );
  }

There's another workaround which will allow you to use internationalization even in the homepage without locale, but you have to use negotiator in your homepage, example:
// app/page.tsx
import { headers } from 'next/headers'
// You can declare this in a separate file and use it in both this page and middleware 
interface MinimalRequest {
   headers: Record<string, string>
}
function getLocale(request: NextRequest | MinimalRequest): string | undefined {
  const negotiatorHeaders: Record<string, string> = {};
  request.headers.forEach((value, key) => (negotiatorHeaders[key] = value));

  const locales: string[] = i18n.languages.map(lang => lang.id);
  const languages = new Negotiator({ headers: negotiatorHeaders }).languages();

  const locale = matchLocale(languages, locales, i18n.base || "id");
  return locale;
}

export function HomePage(): JSX.Element {
  const acceptLanguage = headers().get("accept-language");
  const req: MinimalRequest = {
    headers: {
      "accept-language": acceptLanguage
    }
  }
  const locale = getLocale(req);
  
  // You can render content dynamically depending on locale value (en or de);
  return(
    ...
  )
}


